# Type '[AnyObject!' cannot be implicitly downcast to 'PFObject'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I downloaded a set of project files in order to follow along with a Swift tutorial on Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBnVWWqFZX0&list=UUysEngjfeIYapEER9K8aikw). However, I'm running into an error in XCode when I try to run the application:

> Type '[AnyObject!' cannot be implicitly downcast to 'PFObject'; did
>   you meant to use 'as' to force downcast?

The error takes place within the following lines of code:

```
if !error{
                for object:PFObject! in objects{
                    self.timelineData.addObject(object)
                }
```

XCode tries to fix the problem by adding "as Objects" or something similar immediately after "in objects" and it doesn't seem to fix the problem. I haven't made any changes to the project source files. You can download them yourself by clicking on the link in the video description. The error takes place in the TimelineTableViewController.swift file in the loadData() function.

I'm currently using Xcode 6 beta 4. I have a feeling the code was written using an earlier beta version. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `objects` is of type `[AnyObject!]`. In Swift, you cannot implicitly cast to another type in a loop like you are trying. You have two options.

Cast the whole array:

```
if let pdfObjects = objects as? [PFObject!] {
    for object in pdfObjects {
        // ...
    }
}
```

or cast each element:

```
for object in objects {
    if let pdf = object as? PDFObject! {
        // ...
    }
}
```